# How can I remove hash from form action URL in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have form with action

`action="/users#addUserModal"`

When there is errors in form, after redirect bootstrap modal will open automatically. but when no errors modal is still shown.

```
$data = $request->safe()->only(['first_name', 'last_name', 'birth_date', 'username', 'is_admin', 'password']);
$user = User::create($data);
if ($user->exists) {
    session()->flash("success", "User saved");
        return redirect('admin');
    }
return back()->with('error', 'User not saved');
```

how to make this redirect to admin without hashtag?

Answer (score 2):

```
protected function getRedirectUrl()
{
    return parent::getRedirectUrl() . '#addUserModal';
}
```

i fixed it by adding this to request class.